# SQL Server Configuration Manager cannot be found

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-config-manager

After installing SQL Server 2008, I cannot find the `SQL Server Configuration Manager` in `Start / SQL Server 2008 / Configuration Tools` menu.

What should I do to install this tool?

Comment: I have this tool on my machine and shortcut with target `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe /32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc`. Do you have such *.msc file on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I have both these files on my computer. When running SQLServerManager10.msc, it showed the following message: MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly.
Name: SQL Server Configuration Manager
CLID: {D52E5F54-75D9-4A93-91B7-2215EA5CBED2}

Comment: Select repair option can fix the problem.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1002999/2115

Answer (score 540):

If you happen to be using Windows 8 and up, here's how to get to it:

- The newer Microsoft SQL Server Configuration Manager is a snap-in for
  the Microsoft Management Console program.
- It  is not a stand-alone
  program as used in the previous versions of Microsoft Windows
  operating systems.
- SQL Server Configuration Manager doesn’t appear as
  an application when running Windows 8.
- To open SQL Server
  Configuration Manager, in the Search charm, under Apps, type:

  `SQLServerManager15.msc` for [SQL Server 2019] or

  `SQLServerManager14.msc` for [SQL Server 2017] or

  `SQLServerManager13.msc` for [SQL Server 2016] or

  `SQLServerManager12.msc` for [SQL Server 2014] or

  `SQLServerManager11.msc` for [SQL Server 2012] or

  `SQLServerManager10.msc` for [SQL Server 2008], and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Text kindly reproduced from [SQL Server Configuration Manager changes in Windows 8](http://babyraj.com/sql-server-configuration-manager-changes-windows-8/)

---

Detailed info from MSDN: [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Leniel. This is absolutely ridiculous. Why in the world MS saw fit to hide a commonly used application is beyond me. Just another reason for me to despise Windows 8.

Comment: @Gizmo: yeah... they really do some crazy stuff beyond the rational thinking. :)

Comment: I hope Windows 9 put SQL Server Configuration Manager back to its rightful place.

Comment: @OldGeezer me too! BTW, I liked your profile message about what to know/don't know/should know... :D

Comment: Same with Windows 10. FYI for SQL Server 2014 it is `SQLServerManager12.msc`; obvious I know...

Comment: WIN 10, found it in c/windows/system32/SQLServerManager but its useless, all settings are not accessible...

Comment: Thanks alot. Wrote it in Windows 10 search bar and found it finally

Comment: Thank you Leniel. Just so you and the commentors know. I have two Windows 10 machines.  The one shows it the other does not...

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on the main post, a repair will more than likely fix the issue. It worked for me. It's found under the `Maintenance` section of the installer, as opposed to `Installation`

Comment: Mine startup type is automatic but does not start on system reboot or startup. I am using win 10 and MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Thanks, widows just did an update and I couldn't figure out how to start my server instance.

Comment: If you get an error `cannot connect to wmi provider` use the workaround from this article (run in cmd with admin rights!): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956013/error-message-when-you-open-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-sql-se

Answer (score 168):

On windows 10 
Control Panel→Administrative Tools→Computer Management

[image: Win 10 SQL configuration manager]

Comment: Thanks. If youre still having problems starting service  - run configuration manager as administrator

Comment: Just for the ease, you can open Computer Management by typing `compmgmt.msc` from run window or search panel.

Comment: SQL Server Configuration still not found

Comment: How awsome it is, I can open it even without SQLServerManager12.msc -- which I couldn't find.

Comment: I don't see it.

Answer (score 76):

I know this is old but you can directly browse it using this paths..

SQL Server 2019 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc

SQL Server 2017 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc

SQL Server 2016 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc

SQL Server 2014 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc

SQL Server 2012 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc

SQL Server 2008 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc

source is from ms site
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx

One can also specify `%systemroot%` for the path of Windows directory. For example:

SQL Server 2019: %systemroot%\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc

Comment: How can it be accessed if it's not at this location?

Comment: @thnkwthprtls, I added an example for the installation agnostic location.

Comment: The other answers didn't work for me, but this did, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

From SQL Server 2008 Setup, you have to select "Client Tools Connectivity"  to install SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: This was installed in my instance (SQL 2014 on Windows 10) but the Configuration Manager was no where in the application list. Entering the full msc file name into the search does load it though

Comment: A repair fixed my problem though

Answer (score 19):

This path worked for me. on a 32 bit machine.

**C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe /32 C:\Windows\system32\SQLServerManager10.msc**

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: I don't agree with you. This does provide an answer (*"where is the tool? I cannot find it"*). It certainly was the right answer for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have any version of SQLServerManagerXX.msc, then you simply do not have it installed. I noticed it does not come with SQL server management studio 2019.

It's available (client-connectivity tools) in the [SQL Server Express edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) or  [SQL Server Developer edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) which is good for dev/test (non-production) usage.

Comment: This is what I needed. SQL Server Management Studio version 18 just doesn't come with Configuration Manager. More detail on this is available on this Super User answer: https://superuser.com/a/1513757/1307460

Comment: THANK YOU this saved me

Answer (score 5):

you need to identify sql version.

SQLServerManager15.msc for [SQL Server 2019] or

SQLServerManager14.msc for [SQL Server 2017] or

SQLServerManager13.msc for [SQL Server 2016] or

SQLServerManager12.msc for [SQL Server 2014] or

SQLServerManager11.msc for [SQL Server 2012] or

SQLServerManager10.msc for [SQL Server 2008],

[image]

Step :1) open ssms

```
  2) select version

  3) select above command and run in cmd with admin right.
```

Comment: Not quite sure why the downvote ... this does show where to find it, even if it shows a complete lack of having read the question.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server 2017 it is : `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc`

For SQL Server 2016 it is : `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc`

For SQL Server 2016 it is :`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc`

and to **add it back to the start menu, copy it from the original location provided above and paste it to**

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2017\Configuration Tools\
```

This would put back the configuration manager under start menu.

Source: [How to open sql server configuration manager in windows 10?](https://qawithexperts.com/questions/359/how-to-open-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Configuration Manager is located at **"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManagerXX.msc"**.

So, to find it in your Windows Machine, put **"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager"** without **"XX.msc"** to the search box as shown below. *I could find **"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc"** in my Windows Machine as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Paste this line in folder path url in file explore: 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc
then press enter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to this location `C:\Windows\System32` and find `SQLServerManager` . Worked for me. Configuration manager was there but somehow wasn't showing up in search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can also launch mmc.exe and choose the SQL Server Configuration Manager from Add Remove Snap-ins:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\System32\SQLServerManager15.msc

The version may be different

```
SQLServerManager<version>.msc
```

Answer (score 0):

In our checklist at work forgot that you actually need to install SQL Server also, if you have a license you can download it from: https://my.visualstudio.com/