# SQL Server Express cannot connect error: 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol

Tags: sql-server, network-protocols

I cannot connect to my local SQL Server Express (2012, but the version shouldn't matter) from my server (Windows 2008 R2) to use a tool on it (APEX SQL Data Diff if you are wondering). I can browse the network servers fine, and select my local instance from the dropdown of available servers, but when I go to search tables on the server, it times out with this error message (same is true of SSMS).

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 28 - Server doesn't support strong text
>   requested protocol) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)*

I have enabled the firewall - that's not it.

I have allowed remote connections - that's not it.

SQL Server Browser service is on and passed through the firewall - that's not it.

I can connect fine with the same tools ***TO*** the server, but ***FROM*** the server it fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Thanks to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/22/sql-server-2005-connectivity-issue-troubleshoot-part-i.aspx) for getting me somewhere with the error message.
The issue is the necessary network protocols are disabled by default in SQL Server Express. I had to go to Sql Server Configuration Manager locally and turn on "Named Pipes" and "TCP/IP".
After that, you need to restart the SQL Server Browser and SQL Server(instance) services.

[image: SQL Server Config manager]

While I did not have to, you may also need to check in "SQL Server Network Configuration" under "Protocols" for settings that need adjusted there.

Comment: +1 - I have been struggling with this.  You deserve a medal.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Then why not +1 the quetion as well as the answer?

Comment: This helped me as well, I had the same problem, but I had to do it under the SQL Server Network Configuration as well.

Comment: In particular check the Protocols for SQLEXPRESS, they are disabled by default.

Comment: If anyone can't find Configuration Manager, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844771/sql-server-configuration-manager-not-found) is what helped me find it.

Comment: Absolute legend! The mystery remains as to WHY we have to go and do this, and also why a core app using dbup connected fine, where-as another which used SqlConnection directly failed.

Comment: The Client Protocols were already enabled for me, but enabling same protocols under "SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS" worked for me!

Answer (score 16):

SQL Configuration Manager:

[image: SQL Configuration Manager]

Before checking enabled **SQL Server Client Protocols**, you should check **SQL Server Network Configuration** → **Protocols for SQLEXPRESS**.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Do I need to restart after doing this?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign yes!

Comment: @PrimeByDesign - [Better late than never, for completeness' sake] No - only restart the affected services; saves a server restart.

Answer (score 13):

Don't forget to also check under "SQL Server Network Configuration" -> Protocols for **YourInstance**. I was a bonehead and forgot to look there too.

Comment: ...And restart the associated services.