# Can not connect to a SQL Server express database with VB.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am attempting to connect to a SQL Server Express Database through VB.net.   As I run my connect string I am getting an error.  Here is the code that I am using to connect.  It works fine for another SQL Server database, however it errors out with the sql server express database.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public sqlCnn As SqlConnection

Dim strCONN As String = "Data Source=CAFS\ADEMERO;Initial Catalog=OurDB;User ID=sa;Password=PASSWORD1!"

Try
    sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(strCONN)
    sqlCnn.Open()

    Return True
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, 
              "Content Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
    Return False
End Try
```

Any assistance you can lend would be a great help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Isn't the Sql Express instance called SQLEXPRESS? Not ADEMERO.

Comment: check your connection string

Comment: I tried that as well and it did not work.  I think it has something to do with the protocols being disabled.  I am looking into it.

Comment: I am getting "Error 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol"

Comment: maybe this helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238219/sql-server-express-cannot-connect-error-28-server-doesnt-support-requested-p]

Comment: I just tried that and that did not work either.  Now I am baffled.

Comment: I got it!  I also had to change the enable setting for the protocol on the server side.  Thanks for everyone's help!