# Why does SQL Server @@SERVERNAME return my old machine name?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, server-name

I just stumbled across an issue in my SQL Server 2008 R2 - When I call `@@SERVERNAME`, it's returning my OLD computer's machine name, rather than the current one. Why is this? And how can I fix it? SQL Server somehow is remembering the old machine name.

Comment: Probably stored on the kernal databases during the installation.

Comment: Thanks for the previous answers, helped me fix my issue. Just a note to others, if you want the whole server name like returned from @@SERVERNAME, you can use `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName');`

Comment: Just an interesting thing to add - I just changed a machine name running SQL Server 2014 - and it did this task automatically.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is well known and documented, see [Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx):

> When you change the name of the computer that is running SQL Server,
>   the new name is recognized during SQL Server startup. You do not have
>   to run Setup again to reset the computer name. Instead, use the
>   following steps to update system metadata that is stored in
>   sys.servers and reported by the system function @@SERVERNAME:

```
sp_dropserver <old_name>;
GO
sp_addserver <new_name>, local;
GO
```

You can also use [`SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) which is guaranteed to always return the updated name:

> **MachineName** Windows computer name on which the server instance is
>   running. For a clustered instance, an instance of SQL Server running
>   on a virtual server on Microsoft Cluster Service, it returns the name
>   of the virtual server.

`SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')` will return the current active node in a cluster, or the same value as 'MachineName' on a non-clustered instance.

Edit (by a 3rd party) to add WEFX's comment in case anyone misses it:

> Also, you'll need to restart your SQL services (or reboot the SQL Server) in order for `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` to return the accurate (new) servername

Comment: Also, you'll need to restart your SQL services (or reboot the SQL Server) in order for 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME' to return the accurate (new) servername.

Comment: declare @s varchar(50); 
    select @s = 
cast(SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') as varchar); 
    exec sp_dropserver @@servername; 
    exec sp_addserver @s,local;

Answer (score 5):

I have tried all the possible solutions and the approved answer didn't work for me. I have surfed a bit and come up with the perfect solution. I hope somebody find this helpful.

1) Open registry by **Window + R** key. Type **regedit**

2) Go to ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server*** You will see plenty of numbered directories ( 100,120,130 ....)

OR

you can simply type ***"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\"*** in the address bar of Registry Editor

3) go through all the numbered directories and see if you can find "**Machines**" directory inside

4) Once you find "**Machines**" change the **OriginalMachineName** key to the server name you want it to be. That's actually Original machine name when the windows was first installed.

PS: My path was OriginalMachineName > *Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Machines*

Comment: Interestingly, for AWS SQL Server AMIs the value at this registry location is different than the default machine name when you spin up a new machine, which is then likely different if you manually name the machine.  The only solution that works consistently across our machines is using SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') instead of @@SERVERNAME.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is because the instance was a default installation and inherited the machine name at the time and has kept it.
Try this?

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can get an error `There are still remote logins or linked logins for the server 'yourServerName'` when you run `sp_dropserver 'oldServerName';`

If you have this kind of error then try to run `sp_dropserver 'oldServerName', 'droplogins';` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, with **two SQL queries** below, check **your Windows device name** and **your MSSQL server name** respectively:

```sql
SELECT HOST_NAME()  -- Get Windows device name
SELECT @@SERVERNAME -- Get MSSQL server name
```

Now, you could check **your Windows device name "DESKTOP-NEW"** and **your MSSQL server name "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** respectively as shown below:

[image]

Next, with **the SQL queries** below, you can drop **your old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** and add **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"**:

```sql
EXEC sp_dropserver 'DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS'       -- Drop server
GO
EXEC sp_addserver 'DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS', local -- Add server
GO
```

Now, you could drop **the old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** and add **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** as shown below:

[image]

But, even if you check **your MSSQL server name** again, **your MSSQL server name** is still **the old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** as shown below. *But no worries, in spite of that, **the old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** is actually dropped properly and **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** is actually added properly:

[image]

If you really want to check that **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** is actually added properly, restart **MSSQL** with **SQL Server Configuration Manager(SSCM)**. This is [**How to find SQL Server Configuration Manager in your Windows Machine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844771/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-be-found/73455807#73455807):

[image]

Then, if you check **your MSSQL server name** again, **your MSSQL server name** is now **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Note that HOST_NAME() returns the machine name where the SSMS instance is executing, not the Server host of the SQL Server you're connected to. If you are connected to a remote SQL Server instance via SSMS, HOST_NAME() will give you YOUR machine name, not the name of the SQL Server instance. You should use SERVERROPERTY('MachineName') instead.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I couldn't drop the **old** name; I could restart MSSQL or the VM all I wanted, `@@SERVERNAME` kept returning the old name while every other method (including `SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME')`) was returning the new name, which was causing all sorts of issues. Turns out dropping the **new** name and re-adding it (and restarting MSSQL of course) fixes this odd issue:

```
sp_dropserver <new_name>; GO
sp_addserver <new_name>, local; GO
```