# Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456 by login with "sa" through SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, connection, database-connection, ssms, error-code

I'm getting error 18456 from SQL Server Management Studio when I try to connect Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication as in the pictures below.

Windows Authentication
[image]

SQL Server Authentication
[image]

I want to implement the solution in this link: [Login to Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923015/login-to-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456) but I can't start the engine in no way. Also, I don't know my password for SQL Server Authentication.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried the default SA passwords? `Password123`, or the admin / root password for the account that installed it

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx)? Was one of the first results when I Googled for this.

Comment: @scsimon Yes I tried as this link's descriptions.. http://support.webecs.com/kb/a867/what-is-the-default-password-for-the-sa-login.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login to Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923015/login-to-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456)

Answer (score 10):

I have seen this problem very often with SQL Server 2012 and later versions (usually with new installations) the reason is SQL Server 2012 and later version do not give window Administrators automatically the admin rights in SQL Server.

This will leave you with no access to the SQL Server at all, in this case I use the following approach:

1. Run SQL Server configuration Manager.

   Location for SQL Server configuration Manager:

> ```
> SQL Server 2019    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc
> SQL Server 2017    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc
> SQL Server 2016    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc
> SQL Server 2014    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc
> SQL Server 2012    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc
> SQL Server 2008    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc
> ```

2. `Right-Click` the SQL Server Service and go to `Properties`.
3. Go to `Startup Parameters` tab and add `-m` parameter there. This will cause the SQL-Server to run in Single-User mode.
4. `Restart` the SQL Server service, make sure the SQL Server agent doesn't start, if it does start it may obtain the single available connection to the SQL Server.
5. Once the SQL Server Service has restarted successfully, Right-Click SSMS and `Run as Administrator`.
6. At this point SQL Server would let you connect to SQL Server as Administrator, add your domain account to SQL Server assign `SysAdmin` role.
7. Close the Management Studio, go back to the SQL Server configuration Manager remove `-m` from the startup parameters. Restart the SQL Server service and tadaaa.

Also do not do this on a server that is being used by others.

Comment: what is the domain account mentioned in the solution means ? in this line "dd your domain account to SQL Server assign SysAdmin role."

Comment: On your server click on security -> Logins -> your_username -> Server Roles ->  SysAdmin -> OK

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error:

[image]

1. When logging in with **the default user "sa"** and **the wrong password**.
2. When logging in with **the default user "sa"** without restarting **MSSQL(SQL Server)** after changing **"Server authentication"** from **"Windows Authentication mode"** to **"SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"**.

The solution for **"1"** is changing **the password for "sa"** whether or not you forgot **the password** or don't know **the default password for "sa"**. *You can log in with **"sa"** and **Empty password** if you keep **"Password:"** and **"Confirm password:"** blank, then apply:

[image]

The solution for **"2"** is when changing **"Server authentication"** from **"Windows Authentication mode"** to **"SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"**:

[image]

You will get this message below. So, as the message says, **"Server authentication"** is still **"Windows Authentication mode"** until restarting **MSSQL** with  **SQL Server Configuration Manager(SSCM)**:

[image]

> Some of your configuration changes will not take effect until SQL Server is restarted.

So, you need to restart **MSSQL** with **SQL Server Configuration Manager(SSCM)** as shown below. This is [**How to find SQL Server Configuration Manager in your Windows Machine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844771/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-be-found/73455807#73455807):

[image]

If you use **these 2 solutions above**, you will log in with **the default user "sa"** and **the password**.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to install a new instance of SQL Server and attach any databases to the new instance, but this can be tricky for a variety of reasons, especially if you do not have a recent backup of the `master` database.

Therefore, I'd suggest following the advice given by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004) and start the instance in single-user mode, which will then allow any local administrator on the machine where the instance is installed to gain access and correct the authentication issues (resetting passwords etc.).

Of course, this presumes that you have access to a administrator account on the machine, which hopefully you do.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue I faced and the solution mentioned on this post worked for me :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395581/4409488

What it basically says is that you have to change default login mode which is set to **Windows authentication** only to **SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode**.

*Right click on the server => SelectProperties => Security page => Server authentication =>* Select **SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode** radio button

*Restart* the SQL server from **Services**. And you should be good to go.

Comment: it is good to add url/resource to support your answer but you should add relevant details from url as part of answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some more description.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a specific case of

```
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: ##.##.##.##]
```

and its companion message

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
```

with respect to SQL Server 2014, Windows Server 2019, and SOLIDWORKS professional document management.

Summary

*Test* a different and less complex password.

Detail

My first successfully functioning credential contained 14 characters: letters upper & lower case, numbers, and symbols from this set "$!%^(){}[];:<>?". This enabled a SOLIDWORKS professional document management client stack to communicate with a remote SQL Server Express 2014 stack via the SA database account without the above error.

Searching on "SQL Server 2014 password restrictions" led to this helpful post
    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/52eda46d-5814-45a0-b676-4676f0853474/invalid-password-symbols-for-sql-server-2014-login?forum=sqlsecurity

These links in the accepted answer--while not definitive for SQL Server 2014 nor for Windows Server 2019 credentials--did jog me out of my specific rut:

- test a different credential
- reduce complexity: try a 14 character instead of 48 character password; apply a more constrained symbol set

  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756109(v=ws.10).aspx
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722458(v=vs.85).aspx

TBD - replace above links with definitive links for

- password specification documents for the SQL Server database family
- password specification documents for the computer (local), workgroup, AD domains
- documents elucidating specific alterations to passwords that policy can cause to occur in relevant authorization processing systems.

Server-side *and* client-side authorization stacks may not adhere to the same specifications and limitations. Detailed knowledge of both may be required to achieve functionality first, then some desired level of security.

May your enlightenment be swifter than mine, with fewer bruises.

Answer (score 0):

1. login with windows authentication
2. right click on server connection
3. select properties
4. select Security on left panel
5. check SQL Server and Windows Authentication
6. restart your sql server service
7. enjoy ... :-)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the sql server log file first to know the state number. Then, find base on that state number. As for me, it's faster to find out after I know state number. I started this useful link https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Answer (score 0):

Above marked answer looks good but also for Troubleshooting Make sure username, password are correct.
Try running SSMS as administrator and logging in.
If using AD username with windows authentication then make sure account is not locked out.

If recently changed AD username password then try log off and log back in.

Please refer full article on [sqlserver-dba.co.uk](https://sqlserver-dba.co.uk/sql-server/sql-server-error-18456-severity-14-login-failed-for-use.html)