# Cannot create new user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication, ssms, sql-server-authentication

Everythiing was working fine

My laptop has SQL Server installed

I formatted my laptop

Installed SQL Server (latest version)

then Changed my computer name

Old name was : DESKTOP-EP40R17

New Name is : DELLG3

Now trying to add new user to access databases as i used to do before formatting

I added new user called demo

[image]

And setup the user as I did before

[image]

[image]

[image]

but when I try to add new computer name to Securables

I get this error

[image]

How to fix that and get a new user working?

I tried deleting the user and create a new user still getting no luck accessing the server with new user id

***Edit***

I removed the old server name from SQL Server and added new server name using this script

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME

sp_dropserver 'DESKTOP-EP40R17'

sp_addserver 'DELLG3', 'local'
```

Problem still occurs

I cannot login using the new user ID

Here how it looks like now

[image]

[image]

Here is the error text

```
===================================

Cannot connect to DELLG3.

===================================

Login failed for user 'demo'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error

------------------------------
Server Name: DELLG3
Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
Line Number: 65536


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Comment: So you've created the SQL Login `demo` and assigned `DeepMed` to be its default database... but have you [created a corresponding User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) in the `DeepMed` database and granted permissions to it?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, once you create an SQL login a user gets created for the related DBs automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to restart **MSSQL(SQL Server)** with **SQL Server Configuration Manager(SSCM)** to log in with **SQL Server Authentication** as shown below. This is [**How to find SQL Server Configuration Manager in your Windows Machine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844771/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-be-found/73455807#73455807):

[image]

Because, you would change **"Server authentication"** from **"Windows Authentication mode"** to **"SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"**, then click on **"OK"**:

[image]

Then, you would get this message below:

[image]

> Some of your configuration changes will not take effect until SQL Server is restarted.

So, as the message says, **"Server authentication"** is still **"Windows Authentication mode"** until restarting **MSSQL** with **SSCM**. That's why you couldn't log in with **SQL Server Authentication**, then got the error.

Actually, I got the same error below when I changed **"Server authentication"** from **"Windows Authentication mode"** to **"SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"**, then tried to log in with **SQL Server Authentication** without restarting **MSSQL** with **SSCM**. So, I restarted **MSSQL** with **SSCM**, then I could log in with **SQL Server Authentication** without getting the error:

[image]