# Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for Server '...'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) Invalid Urn filter on server level: filter must be empty,

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, ssms

To rename **my Windows Device name** from **"DESKTOP-OLD"** to **"DESKTOP-NEW"**, I put **"DESKTOP-NEW"**. then clicked on **"Next"**:

[image]

Then, clicked on **"Restart now"** to restart **my Windows PC**:

[image]

After that, I connected to **MSSQL** with **my new server name "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"**. *I use **MSSQL Express edition**:

[image]

Then, I clicked on **"Properties"** from **the user "john"** under **"Security/Logins"**:

[image]

Then, I opened **"Securables" page**:

[image]

Then, I mistakenly checked **"Grant"** for **my old server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** to grant the permissions for it, then clicked **"OK"**:

[image]

But, I got this error below:

[image]

> Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for Server
> 'DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Invalid Urn filter on server level: filter must be empty, or server
> attribute must be equal with the true server name.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

So, from **"Search..."**, I added **my new server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** to **"Securables:"** to grant the permissions for it, then clicked **"OK"**:

[image]

But, I still got this error below:

[image]

So, are there any ways to solve this error?

Answer (score 4):

**Your MSSQL server name** will still be **your old one "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** rather than **your new one "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"**. That's why you got the error and in the error, you can see the error hint message below:

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> ... server attribute must be equal with the true server name.

So, to change **your MSSQL server name** from **your old one "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** to **your new one "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"**, first, with **two SQL queries** below, you need to check **your Windows device name** and **your MSSQL server name** respectively:

```sql
SELECT HOST_NAME()  -- Get Windows device name
SELECT @@SERVERNAME -- Get MSSQL server name
```

Now, you could check **your Windows device name "DESKTOP-NEW"** and **your MSSQL server name "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** respectively as shown below:

[image]

Next, with **the SQL queries** below, you can drop **your old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** and add **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"**:

```sql
EXEC sp_dropserver 'DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS'       -- Drop server
GO
EXEC sp_addserver 'DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS', local -- Add server
GO
```

Now, you could drop **the old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** and add **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** as shown below:

[image]

But, even if you check **your MSSQL server name** again, **your MSSQL server name** is still **the old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** as shown below. *But no worries, in spite of that, **the old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** is actually dropped properly and **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** is actually added properly:

[image]

If you really want to check that **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** is actually added properly, restart **MSSQL** with **SQL Server Configuration Manager(SSCM)**. This is [**How to find SQL Server Configuration Manager in your Windows Machine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844771/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-be-found/73455807#73455807):

[image]

Then, if you check **your MSSQL server name** again, **your MSSQL server name** is now **the new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** as shown below.

[image]

Next, if opening **"Properties"** from **the user "john"** under **"Security/Logins"**:

[image]

Now, you can see that **your new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** is added to **"Securables:"** and **your old MSSQL server "DESKTOP-OLD\SQLEXPRESS"** is removed from **"Securables:"** as shown below:

[image]

Finally, you can grant the permissions for **your new MSSQL server "DESKTOP-NEW\SQLEXPRESS"** by clicking **"OK"** without error:

[image]

Comment: changing the server name to make it matches with hostname worked for me.